# Best way to override propertys behavior in C#

Tags: c#, properties, overriding

Let's say I have a class

```
public class A
{
    int foo;

    public int Foo
    {
        get {
            return foo;
        }
        set {
            if (foo == value) return;
            foo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and a class

```
public class B : A
{
...
}
```

Now, B should extend the behaviour of the property Foo. As I see it, there are three ways to do this:

**Way one** would be to make the poperty virtual in A and override it in B.

```
public class A
{
    int foo;

    public virtual int Foo
    {
        get {
            return foo;
        }
        set {
            if (foo == value) return;
            foo = value;
        }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    int foo;

    public override int Foo
    {
        get {
            return base.Foo;
        }
        set {
            base.Foo = value
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {}

}
```

**Way two** would be to change the setter in A to call a virtual method OnFooChanged and override that in B.

```
public class A
{
    int foo;

    public virtual int Foo
    {
        get {
            return foo;
        }
        set {
            if (foo == value) return;
            foo = value;
            OnFooChanged();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnFooChanged();
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void OnFooChanged() {}
}
```

**Way three** would be to add a PropertyChanged event to A, call OnPropertyChanged("Foo"), and add an event handler in B, which executes the extended behavior.

```
public class A
{
    int foo;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Foo
    {
        get {
            return foo;
        }
        set {
            if (foo == value) return;
            foo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged == null) return;
        PropertyChanged(this, PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {}
}
```

Which way is to be preferred? In what circumstances? Are there significant impacts on performance?

Comment: As you use the term `override` in your question the first is your option.

Comment: I find subscribing to own events to be strange. In option 3, you'd better make `A.OnPropertyChanged` virtual.

Comment: In my opinion way #2 is the good option here. I'd do something like #3 if I'm creating something big like the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for data binding. #2 is much simpler and you'd be overriding what to do after the value of the property has been updated. I'd guess that either of the 3 doesn't have much of an impact in terms of performance. Also, the danger of #1 is that you can set a different property instead when you override the setter.